# Find first four cells in a row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the first four cells along a row that contain values and the type is Double. I want to add the values of the cells to an array and also locate the cells locations for future use. I need to work down 23 rows after as well. Some of the rows don't contain any values. The matrix starts with cell AB3

I've been trying to start with a For loop so I can work down the rows and then having a For loop inside that to create a new array every time I move to a new row. 
The code I need looks something like this.

```
For i = 3 to 27
    For j = 0 to 3
        TIGA(j) = Range(Cells(i, j + 28), Cells(last cell)).Find(first               
        value and then the next three)
```

Again I need to work across from left to right in each row. First I need to add the first four values in a row to an array. Next I need to save the column number for each of the values because I need to know what column they're in later on in my code. After I get the information for one your I need to loop it down for the rest. The array with the values and any variable/array used for the cells location can be restarted every time the code loops through for the new row. Thank you!
[Here's what's the data looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFJni.png)

Comment: In Excel how can you tell if a number is a Double?  The `cell` function will return info about the cell such as the format, but `0.00` returns F2 and `#,##0.00` returns `,2`  Does it matter if it's a double?  Would an integer do as well?

Comment: The values need multiple places after the decimal so an integer type variable won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I changed things up a bit, I think this should suffice:

```
Sub Test()

Dim TIGA As Variant, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

ReDim TIGA(0 To 3)

For i = 3 To 27
    k = 0
    For j = 28 To 40
        If Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(Cells(i, j)) = True And InStr(Cells(i, j), ".") > 0 Then 'make sure it's a double

                TIGA(k) = Cells(i, j)
                k = k + 1

                If k = 3 Then
                    Exit For
                End If

            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I need. I edited my original response so hopefully that clears up any confusion. Thank you though!

Comment: @ep2020 I see.. So how far do the columns extend? Are you trying to utilize `LastCol` here?

Comment: It's from Row 3-27 and Column AB-AN. I'm not sure what LastCol does.

Comment: @ep2020 I've fixed the code. This is creating an array for each row, but it's being overwritten each time it goes to the next row - I'm assuming you're going to be doing something with that array each time within the loop?

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed!